# Why can I not pull an IPv6 address from T-Mobile?

Tags: htc-desire-z, t-mobile, ipv6

I saw that [T-Mobile has enabled IPv6](http://www.extremetech.com/mobile/127213-ipv6-now-deployed-across-entire-t-mobile-us-network) for its network, and I wanted to try it out.

I dropped off my WiFi network, changed my APN to the IPv6-enabled APN (epc.tmobile.com) and was unable to pull an address.

Turns out that they don't support it on this phone (a T-Mobile G2, a.k.a. HTC Vision/HTC Desire Z) yet; they say that only two phones work.

So, I have a couple of queries which led me to post this question:

- Is the IP engine for the EDGE and HSDPA radio actually on-chipset in this phone?
- IPv6 was of course a known thing on the horizon when the phone was released, so if the previous question is a “yes”, then is it at least part of the radio firmware that can be upgraded?

Comment: I've removed the last question; we can't speculate as to why people are boneheaded about IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

The chipset in the G2/Vision/Desire Z doesn't support IPv6, even though the option appears in the OS and [T-Mobile is IPv6 enabled](http://www.extremetech.com/mobile/127213-ipv6-now-deployed-across-entire-t-mobile-us-network).